# Ensemble mean of three continuous random variables and joint probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I need to find the ensemble mean of a quantity containing three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Given by: $\frac{X}{Y+Z}$. To find the ensemble mean, I would need the joint probability distribution of these three variables, i.e.,

$P(X,Y,Z)=P(X)*P(Y|X)*P(Z|X,Y)$ which will be utilized to get the ensemble mean of the quantity $\frac{X}{Y+Z}$. I have relationship between $X$ and $Y$. i.e., $Y=y_0-Xa$, where $y_0$ and $a$ are constants, but I don't have a relationship or equation relating $Y$ and $Z$. My first question is: Can I now write $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X)*P(Y|X)*P(Z|X)$ because $Y$ and $Z$ are independent? Second, while calculating $P(Y|X)=\frac{f(y,x)}{f_Y(y)}$, I need to find the joint PDF of Y and X i.e., $f(y,x)$. How to find it? Can I use the formula $f(y,x)=f_Y(y) * f_X(x) * |dx/dy|$?

If I have a particular probability distribution for $X$ and $Y$, e.g, Poisson for $X$ and normal for $Y$, I still want to also make use of the original relationship $Y=y_0-Xa$.

Comment: First question: yes, Second question: No because $Y = y_0-Xa$ so $(X,Y)$ does not have a density

Comment: Thanks. Can you please let me know how do I find this $f(x,y)$? Do you mean that I need to assign a density to each $X$ and $Y$ to be able to find $f(x,y)$?

Comment: You cannot find $f(x,y)$ because $f(x,y)$ does not exist. If your goal is to compute $E(X/(Y+Z))$, then just write it as $E(X/(y_0-Xa+Z))$$

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thanks. Can you please explain a bit? I thought that I need $P(Y|X)$ and $P(Z|X)$ when I would want to compute $E(X/(Y+Z)$ and to know these I need to know $f(x,y)$ and $f(z,x)$

Comment: That’s true, but $Y$ is a deterministic function of $X$.

Comment: Then I dont need $f(x,y)$ and $f(z,x)$? I am confused.. Please write some details if you could.

Comment: If I ask you to compute $E(X^4\cos X)$ are you going to just compute it or are you going to set $Y = X^2,Z =1/ \cos X$ and then try to compute $E(XY/Z)$ by working with the distributions $X,Y\mid X, Z\mid (X,Y)$?

Comment: Ok I sort of get your point. So essentially it means that since we only have X and Z left, the mean $E(X/(y_0-Xa+Z))$ would require only the joint PDF of X and Z now?

Comment: If both $X,Z$ have a density, then yes. Otherwise you can always compute $$E\left\{ E\left(\frac{X}{y_0-Xa+Z} \mid Z\right) \right\}$$

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try this, X has a Poisson distribution and Z has exponential one. It would be great if you could lay down these details as answer, so others may find it helpful.